# WPF Set GroupBox opacity to 60 percent if a checkbox is ticked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Is there any way in XAML to bind the opacity of a GroupBox depending on if a checkbox is ticked or not?

For example, I want a GroupBox to be 100% opacity if the checkbox is ticked, otherwise it will be 60% opacity if the checkbox is un-ticked.

Can I use element binding to achieve this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chk" />
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=chk}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did exactly what I wanted.